# SSRS - Set Page Break within table

Tags: ssrs, visual-studio-2010

I had to modify a report that was assembled entirely within table (with 1 column and 10 rows). After my modifications, the report now spans multiple pages and I need it to break naturally at one point (i.e. beginning of Row 8).

Is there a way to add a page break in the middle of a  table?

Note, I've tried adding a "Rectangle" and applying the page break with no luck (in the desired Row and then tried in the Row above).

Additional Info:
   - using Visual Studio 2010
   - DBMS = SQL Server 2012 R2

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you can group your data in a way that makes row 1-8 group 1 and the other rows group 2 then you can do a page break at the end of each group.

Comment: Hey James,
Thanks for pointing me in the direction, it helped immensely.

Comment: No worries. Marking the question as answered would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(Since I cannot answer my own question, I'm adding my answer to my question. Thanks again James, I wouldn't have been able to do this without your guidance.)

I figured it out (thanks to James). Here's what I did:

My report had 1 Parent grouping with a Sub-Group at the end of the Parent structure. So it looked something like this:

```
> MAIN GROUP LEVEL (Parent)
  > Main Child 01
    > Main Child 02
      > Main Child 03
        = Details
      > SUBGROUP LEVEL
        > Sub-Child 01
          > Sub-Child 02
            > Sub-Child 03
```

To do what I needed, I had to open the "Group Properties" within the "Grouping Window" (not within the report's "Design" window by right clicking on the Table) for the "SUBGROUP LEVEL". I then enabled/checked all 3 boxes in the "Page Break" configuration section (i.e. "B/w each instance of a group", "Also at the start of a group", "Also at the end of a group"). This produce my desire results of a page break before and after this grouping of data.

Please note that I did not add the page breaks to the "MAIN GROUP LEVEL" b/c it would have produced duplicate breaking for how my report was structured. Since the SUBGROUP data was at the end of my report, I did not have to enable a page break at the MAIN level. If the "MAIN GROUP LEVEL" continued after the "SUBGROUP", I probably would have had to configure a Page Break for this as well.

I hope this info benefits more than just me.